# Print the most frequently occuring letter in a string using AWK

Tags: linux, awk, separator

I have text file

```
('1', 6310445)  [12, 20]_S:0.6:0:ACAAAAAAAAAAA_i_V
('1', 17704109) [12, 31]_S:0.387:0:CCCCCCCCCCCC_i_V
('1', 18922274) [8, 22]_S:0.364:0:AAAAAAAA_i_V
('1', 22750694) [8, 19]_S:0.421:0:TTTTTTTT_i_V
('1', 25564545) [9, 23]_S:0.391:0:AAAAAAAAA_i_V
('1', 29189562) [13, 34]_S:0.382:0:AAAAAAAAAAAAA_i_V
('1', 30166561) [14, 20]_S:0.7:0:TTTTTTTTTTTTTT_i_V
('1', 30450439) [9, 14]_S:0.643:0:AAAAAAAAA_i_V
('1', 30981321) [12, 23]_S:0.522:0:AAAAAAAAAAAA_i_V
```

And I want to print the most frequently occurring letter between the last ":" and first "_".

Which means

"ACAAAAAAAAAAA" => A,
"CCCCCCCCCCCC": => C
.
.
.
.

The output will be

A
C
A
T
A
A
T
A
A

How can I do?

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: what if you have "ACACACACAC" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple reduce-style approach:

```
awk -F: -v ORS= '
    NF>1 && split($NF,a,/_/)>1 {
        for (i=length(s=a[1]); i>0; i--)
            if (++n[c=substr(s,i,1)] > n[r])
                r=c
        print r OFS

        split(r="",n) # reset state
    }
    END { print "\n" }
' textfile
```

If multiple characters appear most frequently (eg. `ABCABCABC`), then the first to reach the maximum will be printed.